# grinder print response text

Tags: java, jython, grinder

I want to print the last response from my GET request using `Grinder`, here is my code:

```
response_string = httpUtilities.getLastResponse().getText()
print str(response_string)
```

I got exception:

```
 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 
  1: ordinal not in range(128) at this line : 

    print str(response_string)
```

My question is how to convert `java.lang.String` .

I got from `httpUtilities.getLastResponse().getText()` into python string? 
Response has
 `charset='utf-8'`

Comment: Jython should be able to use Java Strings without any conversion.  Have you tried just using 'print response_string'?

Comment: Thank you. I tried print(response_string). This one works for me.

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

No conversion should be required.  Change

```
    print str(response_string)
```

to

```
    print response_string
```

Answer (score 1):

I had got the exact same error.. Here's a tweak for this kind of response..

```
try:
   safe_str = response_string.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
   print("text: "+safe_str)
```

This will definitely work. :)